# Alter text to camel case with loop and function javascript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, operators

I'm trying to alter text to camel case with a function. The hyphen in text indicates where the letters need to be capitalized. i.e.  `"this-has-been-camel-cased"` would become  `thisHasBeenCamelCased`. I've altered each word and am wanting to return them as a concatenated string using  `+=` .However when I try to return the string the  `+=` is not recognised or I get an error message stating "fullWord not defined". This is odd as the  `var fullWord` is recognised when I alert it inside the loop ?

Where is the error coming from here. how can I correct it ?

Thaks

```
function camelize(str) {
    var wordArr = str.split('-');
    for (var i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) {
        var ltrArr = wordArr[i].split('');
        var firstLtr = ltrArr[0].toUpperCase();
        var endWord = ltrArr.slice(1).join('');
        var fullWord = firstLtr.concat(endWord);
        var newStr += fullword;
    }
    return newStr;
}

alert(camelize('this-has-been-camel-cased'));
```

Comment: fullWord vs. fullword.  Capital W vs lower case.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler alternative :

```
'this-has-been-camel-cased'.replace(/-./g, function (m) {
    return m[1].toUpperCase();
});
```

Here is a function :

```
function camelize(input, splitter) {
    if (!splitter) splitter = '-';
    return input.replace(new RegExp(splitter + '.', 'g'), function (m) {
        return m[1].toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

And a "no regular expression" version :

```
function camelize(input, splitter) {
    var i = 0;
    if (!splitter) splitter = '-';
    input = input.split(splitter);
    while (++i < input.length) {
        input[i] = input[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input[i].slice(1);
    }
    return input.join('');
}
```

Usage examples :

```
camelize('az-er-ty') // "azErTy"
camelize('az er ty', ' ') // "azErTy"
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems I detect on your code at first sight:

- This code `var newStr += fullword;` is invalid. You cannot use `+=` when declaring a variable
- You have to use `fullWord` and not `fullword` (notice the casing problem with `w`
- You need to declare (at least) `newStr` outside of the for loop, otherwise it will be initialized on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`var newStr += fullword;` is redeclared within the loop, declare it outside with an initial value.

alternative;

```
str = str.replace(/-(.)/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); }).replace(/-/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed with `+=`.

It results from the fact that the purpose of `+=` is to add a string or number to another, but in this case you are using it on a variable that does not yet have anything assigned to it: `newStr` can't have any strings added to it, since it doesn't exist at the time you're invoking it.

What you need is a direct assignment:

```
var newStr = fullword
```

Comment: I've tried declaring the variable as shown above both inside and outside the `for loop`. Both ways only the last word of the string is returned i.e. "Cased".

Comment: I've also tried adding `newStr += fullWord` underneath the declaration to no avail. As well as simply declaring `var newStr; ` then placing `newStr += fullWord` under this. They all only return the last word of the string. Any idea how to make it show all words ?